# Skip some array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need some help. In my database have fields

`ID`, `Domain`, `Key`, `Status`

Below is what i have currently in my code

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password'); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblhosting Where domain = 'LiCf8124d0c5724f32d0eaf14fc17fae6f44'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($row);

mysql_close();
```

The question is how can I display only field `domain` and `status`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you can't select only fields that you need?
`$query = "SELECT domain, status FROM tblhosting Where domain = 'LiCf8124d0c5724f32d0eaf14fc17fae6f44'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. If your status and domain field name is 'Status' and 'Domain' :

```
echo $row['Domain'];
echo $row['Status'];
```

Comment: @user133790 u r welcome! And Happy New Year......... :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$query = "SELECT Domain, Status FROM tblhosting Where domain = 'LiCf8124d0c5724f32d0eaf14fc17fae6f44'";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a simple one. After the SELECT simply add the fields you need comma separated.

So for example

```
SELECT domain, status FROM tblhosting Where domain = 'LiCf8124d0c5724f32d0eaf14fc17fae6f44'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select only the fields you want:

```
$query = "SELECT Domain,Status FROM tblhosting Where domain = 'LiCf8124d0c5724f32d0eaf14fc17fae6f44'";
```